# How can I force this jquery to wait until click event has finished?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using an Ajax File Upload, which has overloaded the `onClientUploadCompleteAll` event, in addition to others.  I am performing navigation after clicking the Upload button in jquery, and I want to force the function to wait until `onuploadcompleteall` has executed before I perform the navigation.  Right now it is navigating to the next page before the `uploadcompleteall` runs.  Is there any way to either force it to wait, or get what the user clicked on within the onuploadcompleteall event?

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" CssClass="0001.01" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif" OnUploadStart="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadStart" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" OnUploadCompleteAll="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadCompleteAll" OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadComplete" OnClientUploadCompleteAll="onClientUploadCompleteAll" OnClientUploadStart="onClientUploadStart"></asp:AjaxFileUpload>
```

The `onClientUploadCompleteAll` event:

```
function onClientUploadCompleteAll(sender, e) { //stuff }
```

The file upload event that performs the click:

```
function handleFileUpload(form) {
    number_of_plugin_instances_having_photos = 0;

    $('.upload-photos').map(function(i, el){
        if($('.uploaded-thumbnail', el).length > 0 || $('.uploaded-thumbnail-title', el).length > 0) {
            number_of_plugin_instances_having_photos++;
        }
    });

    if(number_of_plugin_instances_having_photos == 0) {
        form.submit();
    } else {

        //setTimeout(function(){

            number_of_plugin_instances_callbacks_uploaded = 0;

            $('.upload-photos').map(function(i, el){
                if($('.uploaded-thumbnail', el).length > 0 || $('.uploaded-thumbnail-title', el).length > 0) {
                    $('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton', el).trigger('click');
                }
            });
        //}, 1000);

    }
}
```

Calls the file upload event

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: loc + "/SubmitSections",
        data: dataValue,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (data, status) {
        if (data.d != "success") {
            $("#modal-submitting").modal('hide');
            $(".error_message").text("Unable to submit the data entered.  Please try again.  Additional Details: " + data.d);
            $("#modal-error-occurred").modal('show');
        }
        else {
            handleFileUpload(form, true);

            //NEED TO WAIT BEFORE NAVIGATING OTHERWISE COMPLETE ALL DOES NOT EXECUTE
            document.location = "general-appearance.aspx";
        }
    })
    .fail(function (data, status) {
        if (data.d != "success") {
            $("#modal-submitting").modal('hide');
            $(".error_message").text("Unable to submit the data entered.  Please try again.  Additional Details: " + data.d);
            $("#modal-error-occurred").modal('show');
        }
        else {
            handleFileUpload(form, true);

            //NEED TO WAIT BEFORE NAVIGATING OTHERWISE COMPLETE ALL DOES NOT EXECUTE
            document.location = "general-appearance.aspx";
        }
    });//ajax call end
```

Comment: Why not just move the navigation to the end of onuploadcompleteall?

Comment: only because the user has the option of clicking from a navigation menu...I have no way of knowing what the user clicked on from the menu within the onuploadcompleteall. Or at least no way that I know of?

Comment: What about setting the ajax call as not async? `async: false`

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I can use the form action to get the location that the user has chosen to navigate.  In the `onClientUploadCompleteAll` I have placed the following:

```
function onClientUploadCompleteAll(sender, e) {

    //I have more than one photo upload
    number_of_plugin_instances_callbacks_uploaded++;

    if(number_of_plugin_instances_callbacks_uploaded == number_of_plugin_instances_having_photos){
        var first_form = $('form')['0'];
        var nextPage = first_form.action;

        document.location = nextPage;
        //first_form.submit();
    }
}
```